# how to join two tables with the use of subqueries

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to get the customer name from table CUSTOMER and balance from table ACCOUNT. I join both tables but to no avail. Am aware if you want to join two tables that contain the same column name you must use prefix references to column names that exist in multiple tables with either the table name or a table alias and a period (.) or else the error message ORA-00918 column ambiguously defined will show.

```
select c.cfirst, c.clast, a.balance
from customer c, account a
where c.social = a.social AND social in (select social from account where social in (select social
from trans where dotrans > '04/01/2016' and means_of_trans = 'credit'));
```

Comment: And your question is also ambiguous. Kindly explain what issues your are facing with the query. At first glance it seems that you need alias in after the `AND` in main query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `alias` name for the social column. Because both the tables have this column.

Try this:

```
select c.cfirst, c.clast, a.balance
from customer c, account a
where c.social = a.social AND a.social in (select social
                                         from account
                                         where social in (select social

                                                        from trans
                                                        where dotrans > '04/01/2016' and means_of_trans = 'credit'));
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to have sub query for account table again as you are just checking for social value from account table with the social value from trans table.

```
  select c.cfirst, c.clast, a.balance
    from customer c, account a
    where c.social = a.social 
    AND a.social in ( select social
                      from trans where dotrans > '04/01/2016' 
                      and means_of_trans = 'credit'
                     );
```